# How to start stopwatch again after restarting its time?

Tags: javascript, stopwatch, console-input

So I'm just starting to learn JavaScript, like its syntax and logic, therefore I'm still not implementing anything on a web page, just playing with the console before doing any web development with JS.

There's this function I'd like to implement, a restart function where you can start the stopwatch again after having restarted it, which I quite haven't figured out how to do so

Here's the run() function with the logic of all necessary inputs to control the stopwatch (such as a start key, a pause/resume key, a stop and finally a restart key:

```
function run() {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin
    });

    rl.on('line', (input) => {
        if (input.toLowerCase() === 'i') {
            if (!running) {
                if (restarted && paused) { 
                    seconds = 0;
                    minutes = 0;
                    hours = 0;
                    hundredths = 0;
                    laps = [];
                    restarted = false;
                    // restartTime = Date.now(); not sure if this even works as I expect it to.
                }
                startStopwatch();
            }
        } else if (input.toLowerCase() === 'p' && running) {
            paused = !paused;
            console.log('Stopwatch is paused.');
        } else if (input.toLowerCase() === 'd' && running) {
            running = false;
            rl.close();
            console.log('Stopwatch has been stopped.');
        } else if (input.toLowerCase() === 'l' && running && !paused) {
            recordLaps();
        } else if (input.toLowerCase() === 'v' && paused) {
            showLaps();
        } else if (input.toLowerCase() === 'r' && paused) {
            restarted = true;
            console.log('Stopwatch has been restarted.');
        } else if (input.toLowerCase() === 'i' && restarted && paused) {
            startStopwatch();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's what the `Stopwatch()` function looks like, also I showed the `startStopwatch()` func.

```
async function Stopwatch() {
    let startTime = Date.now();
    
    while (running) {
        if (!paused) {
            let currentTime = Date.now(),
                elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
                hundredths = Math.floor(elapsedTime % 1000 / 10)
  
            let Hours = getTimeFormat(hours),
                Minutes = getTimeFormat(minutes),
                Seconds = getTimeFormat(seconds),
                Hundredths = getTimeFormat(hundredths); 
                    
            await clearConsole();
            console.log(`${Hours}:${Minutes}:${Seconds}.${Hundredths}`);
            
            if (elapsedTime >= 1000) {
                startTime = currentTime;
                seconds++;

                if (seconds === 60) {
                    seconds = 0;
                    minutes++;

                    if (minutes === 60) {
                        minutes = 0;
                        hours++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        await sleep(1);
    }
}

async function startStopwatch() {
    running = true;
    await clearConsole();
    await Stopwatch();
}
```

Comment: You'll never get to `else if (input.toLowerCase() === 'i' && restarted && paused)`. If the input is `i`, the first `if` statement handles it.

Comment: Aside: I suggest you convert `input` to lower case once at the beginning, so you don't have to keep writing `input.toLowerCase()` everywhere. `input = input.toLowerCase()`;

Comment: What's wrong with the `restarted = true;` code that you already have when the user restarts the stopwatch?

Comment: @Barmar Tried removing the last else if that covered `i` but it's still not working. I also tried using another key to restart the stopwatch, didn't work.

The `restarted = true` seems to just stop the program but keeps it that way

Comment: Don't you need `running = true;` to make it start again? Why do you need both `running` and `restarted`? I think we need to see the logic in the stopwatch that uses all these variables.

Comment: Already solved it. Thank you so much for letting me know my error on the last `else if`.

Comment: I posted the stopwatch logic in the answer since it was too long to put here

Comment: Answers should be used for solutions, not adding details to the question. I don't see why it wouldn't fit in the question.

Comment: Too many characters

Comment: It's not even close to the limit, which is 30,000 characters.

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should post the solution in an answer.

Comment: I just posted the answer!